# GPU ARM Mali and OpenCL driver

Tags: arm, gpu, opencl

I have my [TinkerBoard](https://www.asus.com/Single-Board-Computer/Tinker-Board/) powered by an ARM-based Mali™-T764 GPU. I am running [Debian linaro v2.0.8 strech](https://tinkerboarding.co.uk/wiki/index.php/Software#Debian).
I am looking for an OpenCL support, how can I enable the GPU MALI with OpenCL 1.2 FP?

If you can advice me to update it I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the binary ARM Mali drivers. How you do that, depends on the distro you're using. On Odroids for example, it comes installed with their Ubuntu.

Once you have it installed, it either comes with OpenCL enabled, or you can simply enable it: create a file `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/mali.icd` and put inside that file the path to the driver, e.g. on my Odroid it's `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/mali-egl/libmali.so`

So first i'd ask on whatever communication channels Debian Linaro has, how to install the binary drivers.

Comment: Either Ubuntu or Debian, is there some already with enabled OpenCL driver or installation procedure for those distros?